# How to call an outer method from within a handler

Tags: java, class, methods, scope, handler

So I have A MouseListener class inside a public class with a few methods.
I have attached the mouseListener to a component in the public class.

The problem is I can't figure out a simple way to call the methods in the public class, whenever I say for example `this.showRemove();` the scope is from within the handler class and not the public class. Here is some example code

```
public class Game {

 public Game() {

  JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
  pnl.addMouseListener(new GameMouseListener());

 }

 public void showRemove(){

  //Code Here

 }


 class GameMouseListener implements MouseListener {

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     this.showRemove(); //Can't Find Symbol Here     

  }

 }  

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `this` in an inner class, you are referring to the instance of the inner class, not the host class.

Since your inner class is not a static inner class, you can access the reference to the host class by using it's class name like so:

```
HostClass {
    doSomething() {}

    class Inner {
        void blah() {
            HostClass.this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Unless the method you're calling is *also* in the inner class, you can avoid the explicit naming and can simply use the method name:

```
void blah() {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `showRemove` is a non-static method of `Game` you need an instance of that class on which to call the method.

You could instead create an anonymous inner class like this:

```
pnl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void MouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
    showRemove();
  }
});
```

This listener will be associated with the running instance of `Game` and will therefore have access to its non-static methods.

Comment: I Tried to do that And I Still wasn't able to access the non-static method when using "this.showRemove" I'm still inside a class

Comment: Ok I figured it out, the problem was that I was using This and should just call the method as it is. Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. This is a pretty common pattern in Java--more often than not, you only need the listener class in one place anyway.

Comment: codelark's answer is better as it give you the freedom to a non-anonymous listener class.

Comment: @Steve Kuo I don't think it's fair to say one approach is better than the other. I think it boils down to context and personal preference. Anonymous inner classes are great when you need a quick one-off listener that won't be reused, but of course they aren't always appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to a Game object to be able to call the method. When you say this.showRemoved() "this" is referencing the MouseListener object instead of the Game object.

One possibility is to have the Game class extend MouseListener, and put the mouseClicked() method inside the Game class.

Comment: Due to the nature of the Game Class, its not possible to extend MouseListener. Is there a way to send the object to the Handler, since if I were to do e.getSource() I would be getting the JPanel not the Game Object.